# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' React in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In this case react index.js calling from mvc in view in home.cshtml like this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="~/reactui/src/index.js"></script>

<div id="root1"></div>
```

index.js in react like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root1'));
root.render(   
    <React.StrictMode>
       <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>      
);
```

getting error Unexpected token '<' when calling from asp.net core mvc cshtml in react index.js
this project in i am add react in asp .net core mvc
there are fronted in used react and backend in use c#(mvc)

Comment: _"getting error Unexpected token '<' when calling from asp.net core mvc cshtml in react index.js"_ What! I doubt you're calling React/JS code from ASP.NET Core. I would normally expect it to be the other way around. If so it makes more sense and would be the result of attempting to parse downloaded content (JSON/JS/CSS) but getting an HTML error page. What errors do you see in your browser's dev tools?